# Permission denied creating /go directory in Jenkins when building a project that uses go modules

Tags: go, jenkins, file-permissions, go-modules

When I try to build a go Jenkins project that uses go modules, I see this error:

`go: writing go.mod cache: mkdir /go: permission denied`

I also see a similar error for every import:

```
project-name/cmd imports
    github.com/antonfisher/nested-logrus-formatter: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd imports
    github.com/gorilla/mux: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd imports
    github.com/pkg/errors: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd imports
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd imports
    github.com/spf13/cobra: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd imports
    github.com/spf13/viper: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd imports
    k8s.io/api/core/v1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/backup imports
    github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/pkg/apis/velero/v1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/backup imports
    github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/pkg/backup: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/backup imports
    github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/pkg/builder: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/backup imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/csisnaprestore imports
    github.com/gosuri/uitable: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/csisnaprestore imports
    github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/v2/pkg/apis/volumesnapshot/v1beta1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/csisnaprestore imports
    k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/pkg/client/clientset/clientset: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/csisnapshot imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/csisnapshot imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/initz imports
    k8s.io/api/apps/v1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/px/appbackup imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/stork/pkg/apis/stork/v1alpha1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/px/credentials imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/openstorage/api: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/repository imports
    gocloud.dev/blob: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/snaprestore imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/snapshot imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/schema: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/snapshot imports
    k8s.io/client-go/dynamic: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/veleroutil imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/cmd/cli/version imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/intstr: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/cli imports
    github.com/go-openapi/swag: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/cli imports
    github.com/spf13/pflag: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/cli imports
    k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/cli imports
    k8s.io/client-go/rest: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/cli imports
    k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/cli imports
    k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd/api: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/core/framework imports
    github.com/hashicorp/go-version: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/core/framework imports
    k8s.io/api/batch/v1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/core/framework imports
    k8s.io/api/batch/v1beta1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/core/framework imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/rand: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/core/loader imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/validation: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/hook imports
    k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/scheme: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/hook imports
    k8s.io/client-go/tools/remotecommand: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/ioutil imports
    github.com/gofrs/flock: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/ioutil imports
    golang.org/x/sys/unix: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    github.com/ghodss/yaml: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/api/storage/v1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/meta: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/resource: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/fields: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/client-go/informers: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/client-go/tools/portforward: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/kube imports
    k8s.io/client-go/transport/spdy: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    gocloud.dev/blob/fileblob: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/objectstore imports
    gocloud.dev/blob/s3blob: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/openstorage/api/client: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/openstorage/api/client/cluster: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/openstorage/api/client/volume: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/openstorage/cluster: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/openstorage/volume: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    google.golang.org/grpc: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    google.golang.org/grpc/credentials: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/px imports
    google.golang.org/grpc/status: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/quiesce imports
    github.com/deckarep/golang-set: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/quiesce imports
    github.com/drone/envsubst: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/stork imports
    github.com/libopenstorage/stork/pkg/client/clientset/versioned/typed/stork/v1alpha1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/utils imports
    k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/pkg/apis/apiextensions/v1beta1: mkdir /go: permission denied
project-name/pkg/velero imports
    github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/pkg/generated/clientset/versioned: mkdir /go: permission denied
```

I am using the [Go](https://plugins.jenkins.io/golang/) Jenkins plugin to change the Go version.

Here is how I am using it in a Jenkins pipeline:

```
def root = tool name: 'Go 1.14', type: 'go'

withEnv(["GOROOT=${root}", "PATH+GO=${root}/bin", "GOBIN=${root}/bin"]) {
  sh 'go version'
  sh './build.sh'
}
```

Note: `./build.sh` builds the project using modules

What is happening, and how can I get my build to work?

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that GOPATH is still defined as `/go`. The build process tries to create this directory, but Jenkins does not have access to create it.

To resolve this issue, define `GOPATH` in your `withEnv` call, so the final `withEnv` code block would look like:

```
withEnv(["GOROOT=${root}", "PATH+GO=${root}/bin", "GOBIN=${root}/bin", "GOPATH=${root}/go"]) {
  sh 'go version'
  sh './build.sh'
}
```

The documentation did not mention defining "GOPATH" here, so it took me a few days to discover this.